# Kafka connection transformations. Parse input string and get a record key

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I use a simple file source reader

```
connector.class=org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
```

File content is a simple JSON object in each line. I found that there is a way to replace a record key and use transformations to do this, like

```
# Add the `id` field as the key using Simple Message Transformations
transforms=InsertKey

# `ValueToKey`: push an object of one of the column fields (`id`) into the key
transforms.InsertKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey
transforms.InsertKey.fields=ip
```

But I got an error

> Only Struct objects supported for [copying fields from value to key],
>   found: java.lang.String

Is there a way to parse string json and get a key from there like I can do with Flume and regex_extractor?

Comment: Your key is a string, not a struct. How would you expect something to be "inserted into" a string?

Comment: I've replaced configuration to
transforms.ReplaceKey.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Key
transforms.ReplaceKey.whitelist=ip
But it still generates an error `Only Map objects supported in absence of schema`

Comment: I found it impossible to do if the source doesn't have a schema. It have to be another plugin with supporting to generate a structured model.

Comment: @SergeiGrigorev, did you figure this out anytime later without source having the schema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there is a way to replace a record key

There is a separate transform called [`org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Key`](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect_transforms)

`InsertKey` will take a value and attempt to insert into a Struct/Map, but you seem to be using a String key

Comment: I changed to ReplaceField$Key, but I still have a problem that my input value doesn't have a schema or something like this

org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [field replacement], found: null

Comment: `org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [field replacement], found: null
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.util.Requirements.requireMap(Requirements.java:38)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField.applySchemaless(ReplaceField.java:133)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField.apply(ReplaceField.java:126)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:38)`

Comment: Hmm. I feel like without a schema, it just doesn't know how to parse your objects. That is why Avro is more preferred than simple JSON

Comment: but I have input log files where every line is a json string. In flume I can use regex_extractor in interceptors. And I tried to do the same with kafka connect. So ... I will try to use other plugin with json support to do this. Anyway, thanks for you help

Comment: Confluent documentation explicitly says Filestream source is only for getting started with connect, not production use cases. Flume, Fluentd, Filebeat are all perfectly fine options for consuming log files to Kafka

Answer (score 2):

When using Transformation on SourceConnector, the transformation is done on the `List<SourceRecord>` that is returned by the `SourceConnector.poll()`

In your case, the `FileStreamSourceConnector` reads the lines of the file and puts each line as a String in the `SourceRecord` object. Therefore, when the transformation gets the `SourceRecord`, it only sees it as a String and does not know the structure of the object.

To solve this problem,

1. Either you modify the `FileStreamSourceConnector` code so that it returns the `SourceRecord` with a valid [Struct](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html) and [Schema](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Schema.html) of your input json String. You can use the Kafka's [SchemaBuilder](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaBuilder.html) class for this.
2. Or in case you're consuming this data in sink connector, you can have KafkaConnect convert it to JSON by setting following config on the sink connector and then do the transformations on the sink connector.

> "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
>   "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"

If you go with the 2nd option, don't forget to put these configs on your SourceConnector.

> "value.convertor":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
>   "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"